# Given a list of offsets, what is the fastest way to read them from a particular Kafka partition?

Tags: apache-kafka

Assume you're given a list of numbers representing offsets of some records within certain (topic, partition). What is the most optimized way to map them into corresponding records?

P.S. There might be quite long gaps in between adjancet numbers and yet sometime they tend to group closely; so you can't assume any specific pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Java API, you can use the `consumer.seek` method to go to those offsets and read the message.

You may also want to adjust the poll size to not grab 500 records at once, or at least disable auto offset commit

Comment: May I grab exactly one at time rather then a batch? For example, by setting `max.bytes` to `0`.

Comment: You can set `max.poll.records=1`